# How can I upload files and form data with jQuery?

Tags: ajax

I would like to upload a file and form data with Jquery. My html;

```
<form id="kayit" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="yazi" />
<input type="file" id="resim" name="resim"/>
<a onclick="kontrolet();" id="yolla">Yolla</a>
</form>
<div id="sonuc"></div>
```

and my js;

```
            function kontrolet()
            {
                var veriler = jQuery("#kayit").serialize();
                //console.log(veriler);
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'form.php',
                    data: veriler,
                    processData: false,
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        jQuery("#sonuc").html("Lütfen Bekleyin....");
                    },
                    success: function(sonuc)
                    {
                        jQuery('#sonuc').html(sonuc);
                    }
                });
            }
```

I have get filename, but this not working. Help ?

Answer (score 0):

You cant upload a file through ajax using simple javascript (one of the reasons is that javascript cannot access the file system at the moment, so it cannot read content to send it on an AJAX request).

For that kind of feature you have to use some plugin that uses action script or java. There are many available online (search ajax file upload), but in my opinion you are better off using an old fashioned POST.

Answer (score 0):

I've used jQuery to upload file in the background using the [AjaxUpload plugin](https://code.google.com/p/ajax-upload) - it builds an iFrame in the background, clones your form and submits the clone to that.